# simple jquery script working alone but not working in my vbulletin page

Tags: jquery, html, vbulletin

Thank you in advance if you are being able to help me as I really can't find out what's wrong.

I'm trying to display an image when mouse hovering a link. Done a lot of research and find a very simple jquery script to do so. I implemented it on my test page and it works perfectly:
http://hearthstonehelp.com/test.html (please note I use direct link in the example below to simplify the test)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hearthstone.com/images/styles/gamingo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hearthstone.com/images/styles/gamingo/js/tooltip_card.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/static/images/cards/03.png" class="hearthstonecardimage" rel="http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/static/images/cards/03.png">Fireball</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Now when implementing the exact same thing in my vbulletin instance here: http://hearthstonehelp.com (despite having the exact same code it doesn't display the image).

My question: what could it be? What kind of test can I do to find the problem? I assume it is a conflict maybe with something else using a similar script and over writting the one I'm trying to implement?

Any thought would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been to http://www.hearthstonehelp.com/showthread.php?463-Card-popup-previews where you tried using the script. After a while I noticed that the image is actually showing in the bottom right of your body. (zoom max out then hover Fireball and you'll see it if you scroll down). The problem is with the element `p` and it's css

I'll edit later if I find what to change. But atleast now you know what the actual problem is.

EDIT: This should work

In your tooltip_card.js change the code into this

```
$("#hearthstonecardimage")
        .css("top",(e.pageY + 10) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + 10) + "px")
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .fadeIn("fast");
```

Comment: OMG I'm trying this out now. Thank you so much. I will let you know!

Comment: if it starts flickering add `+10` at `e.pageY` and `e.pageX`. I'll update that.

Comment: I was going to ask that too :D Thank you so much for resolving this whole issue. To be honest I would never have found by myself :)